# Collections of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a bunch of integers and I want to add them to a particular group. Lets say each group won't exceed 100 integers. I want to be able to add a new group, if necessary (max 100 groups). I want to be able to access all elements in any groups by index (i.e group[2].element[3]). I should also be able to sort the elements in every group.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Elements
{
    private int[] values;  
    public int[] Values    
    {
        get
        {
            return values;
        }
        set
        {
            values = value;
        }
    }
}

class Solution {
    static void Main(String[] args) {    
        Elements[] groups = new Elements[100];
        groups[0].SetValue(5, 1); // fill group[0] elements[1] with value 5
        int v = groups[0].GetValue(2);  // read value located at index 2
    }
}
```

For groups, perhaps I could make a list of arrays. I suppose I can make a class called Elements, and for each new group, I instantiate a new element. 
Could you please provide info about how to fix this code, if I want to use the Elements class?

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed and corrected it.

Comment: `Could you please help fix this code?` Anything specific you have in mind? Or do you just want us to write this code for you?

Comment: I described what I have in mind. I've been struggling to understand classes for a long time and I would appreciate if somebody would build the code to do what I want to do.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. If you have a specific question or problem in mind, then we can help. But you'll be hard-pressed finding someone on here to just code you up something for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `List<int> myGroup = new List<int>()`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the List of integers for my problem.